# How to throw an exception to the client over wcf callback

Tags: wcf, exception, callback

I have a wcf service which has a one way operation and it sends the result in a callback. Here is my service definition

```
 [ServiceContract(CallbackContract = typeof(IIrmCallback), SessionMode = SessionMode.Required)]
    public interface IFileService
    {
       [OperationContract(IsOneWay = true, IsInitiating = false, IsTerminating = false)]
       [ServiceKnownType(typeof(StatementFile))]
       [ServiceKnownType(typeof(InvoiceFile))]
       void UploadFile(IFile file);
    }

    public interface IFileCallback
    {
       [OperationContract]
       void FileProcessed(string result);
    }

public MyService : IFileService
{
  IFileCallBack callbackchannel;
  object result;
  public void UploadFile(IFile file)
{
   callbackChannel = OperationContext.Current.GetCallbackChannel<IIrmCallback>();
   Task.Factory.StartNew(() => ProcessFile(file));
}
private ProcessFile(IFile file)
{
// file gets processed
 callbackChannel.FileProcessed(result)
}
}
```

So now if there is some error during the file processing is there someway I can throw an exception back to the caller in the callback?

Answer (score 3):

You can use [FaultException](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms576199.aspx)

When an operation throws an exception, a FaultException will be returned to the client.

Comment: The UploadFile is a oneway operation, I fixed the code sample so Fault exception thrown doesnt reach the client.

Comment: @Satish: s Michael said, you must add a [FaultContract(typeof(YourCustomFault))] on your void UploadFile(IFile file);

Comment: You cannot set FaultContract attribute and OneWay =true attribute together

Comment: You're right, I just checked. You cannot remove the OneWay attribute?

Answer (score 1):

You need to implement a FaultContract in your service interface specifying the types of faults that are possible in that given method and then throw a new fault that inherits from FaultException within the method.

On the client, make sure to catch and handle FaultException and Exception objects individually because Exceptions will cause the WCF channel to fault and it cannot be reused, while a FaultException will allow you to continue using the existing channel.